# How to dynamically position info box based on the position of the different element with same class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I position my info box based on the position of the element? currently there is multiple element using the same class. This causes the info box to take the position of another element with same class instead. This is what I have done so far.

credit of the password strength meter to: http://elationbase.com/jquery/jquery-password-requirements/index.html#demos

**login.html**
class in question: .pr-password

```
<div class="login-wrap" id="cust-signup-wrap">
    <h2 class="title-3">Agent New Sign-Up </h2>
    <form role="cust-signup" class="signup" id="" action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email" class="form-control" style="height: 35px;"></div>
     <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="pr-password form-control pass" style="height: 35px;">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="login-wrap" id="merchant-signup-wrap">
    <h2 class="title-3">Merchant New Sign-Up </h2>
    <form role="cust-signup" class="signup" id="" action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email" class="form-control" style="height: 35px;"></div>
     <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="pr-password form-control pass" style="height: 35px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Show Message reusable function
                var showMessage = function () {
                    if (numCharactersDone === false || useLowercaseDone === false || useUppercaseDone === false || useNumbersDone === false || useSpecialDone === false) {
                        $(".pr-password").each(function(index, value) {
                            console.log(index, value)
                            // Find the position of element
                            var posH = $(this).offset().top,
                                itemH = $(this).innerHeight(),
                                totalH = posH+itemH,
                                itemL = $(this).offset().left;
                            // Append info box tho the body
                            $("body")     .append(messageDiv);
                            $("#pr-box")  .addClass(o.style)
                                .fadeIn(o.fadeTime)
                                .css({top:totalH, left:itemL});
                        });
                    }
                };
```

**css**

```
/*for password strength meter*/
#pr-box {
    font: 13px/16px sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1500;
    /*top: 468.171875px;*/
    /*left: 61px;*/
    display: none;
    width:300px;
    max-width:100%;
}
#pr-box i {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #23a86d;
}
#pr-box-inner {
    margin-top: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
#pr-box p {
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
#pr-box ul {
    padding:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
#pr-box ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding:7px;
}
#pr-box ul li span {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin-right:15px;
}
#pr-box.light {
    color:#2d2f31;
}
#pr-box.light p {
    background-color:#23a86d;
    color:#f1f1f1;
}
#pr-box.light ul {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
#pr-box.light ul li span {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    border:3px solid #23a86d;
}
#pr-box.light ul li span.pr-ok {
    background-color:#23a86d;
    border:3px solid #23a86d;
}
#pr-box.dark {
    color:#f1f1f1;
}
#pr-box.dark p {
    background-color:#23a86d;
}
#pr-box.dark ul {
    background-color:#2d2f31;
}
#pr-box.dark ul li span {
    background-color:#2d2f31;
    border:3px solid #23a86d;
}
#pr-box.dark ul li span.pr-ok {
    background-color:#23a86d;
    border:3px solid #23a86d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have managed to solve this issue. Hopefully it would somehow help future stackoverflow-er in their design thinking.

I have included a if condition to check on the styling of my html as it has pop-up. You could look into this direction if you needed to apply on multiply style. If you do not have pop up, you could assign unique ID and find the id corresponding to it.

**JavaScript**

```
var showMessage = function() {
    if (numCharactersDone === false || useLowercaseDone === false || useUppercaseDone === false || useNumbersDone === false || useSpecialDone === false) {
        $(".pr-password").each(function(index, value) {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) { //added this line in
                // Find the position of element
                var posH = $(this).offset().top,
                    itemH = $(this).innerHeight(),
                    totalH = posH + itemH,
                    itemL = $(this).offset().left;
                // Append info box tho the body
                $("body").append(messageDiv);
                $("#pr-box").addClass(o.style)
                    .fadeIn(o.fadeTime)
                    .css({
                        top: totalH,
                        left: itemL
                    });
            }
        });
    }
};
```